# Apache Ozone Java API: PERMISSION_DENIED for read and create keys of file-type

Tags: java, security, hadoop, ozone

I configure Ozone connection as follows:

```
 OzoneConfiguration ozoneConfiguration = new OzoneConfiguration();
 ozoneConfiguration.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/ozone-site.xml"));
 ozoneConfiguration.set("ozone.om.address", "ofs://ozone:9862");
 OzoneClient ozClient = OzoneClientFactory.getRpcClient(ozoneConfiguration);
 ObjectStore objectStore = ozClient.getObjectStore();
 OzoneVolume ozoneVolume = objectStore.getVolume(VOLUME);
 OzoneBucket ozoneBucket = ozoneVolume.getBucket(BUCKET);
```

And trying to list files:

```
List<OzoneFileStatus> fileStatuses = ozoneBucket.listStatus(filesDirectory, false, filesDirectory, 10000);
```

When filesDirectory constraint key, which also has directory type, this is work.

For example: "filesDirectory = home", and home includes folder "user".
But if filesDirectory constraint key, which also has file type (for example "filesDirectory = home/user", and home/user includes file.parquet.snappy), I receive the error:

> PERMISSION_DENIED
> org.apache.hadoop.ozone.om.exceptions.OMException: User user@QA.DF.OCP.COM READ permission to access key Volume: data Bucket:bucket Key: /home/user

Similarly for create operations.
I can create new folder in home-directory. But, when I'm trying to create new file:

```
 ozoneBucket.createKey(fileName, fileLen)
```

I receive similar error:

> PERMISSION_DENIED
> org.apache.hadoop.ozone.om.exceptions.OMException: User user@QA.DF.OCP.COM doesn't have CREATE permission to access key Volume:data Bucket:bucket Key:file1.snappy.parquet

Ozone Client version is: hadoop-ozone-client 1.1.0

This problem is actual, when I'm only using Java API!
In terminal (for example, hdfs dfs -ls ofs://ozone) everything works well!
By Apache Range and terminal (-ls -R command) I see, that user has all necessary permissions.

So I suppose, that problem is located at some settings of OzoneClient in Java project. May be I need to override some properties in ozone-site.xml?

What am I doing wrong?